# How to keep the original resolution of inserted image in sharelatex?

Tags: fonts, graphics, sharelatex, resolution

I have exported the flowchart either in `JPEG`, and `PNG` format, and tried to insert this images to my latex project. Unfortunately, the image was blurred, text in the image can be shown normal if I open it on image viewer, but in latex, text hard to read it. My image resolution is `1002 x 1132`. Why image resolution can't be preserved?  How can I avoid blurred image in latex? Can anyone help me out how to resolve this issue? Any idea please?

Here is my latex code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.685\textheight, scale=0.9]{workflow}
    \centering
    \caption{workflow}
    \label{fig: workflow}
\end{figure}
```

This is the original image I want to insert on my latex project [image: original imaged]. (Note that this image is generated by `draw.io` online tool)

This is the screenshot of the blurred image in latex:

[image: inserted image in sharelatex]

Comment: Latex does not change the resolution, it just embeds the image. Try with `\includegraphics{workflow}` , this won't fit on your page, but you will see that the original quality of the image is preserved. To avoid this problem, its better to include such an image in vector format, for example as `.pdf`

Comment: See my answer - in principle you could use the same code, but I'd advise for not using `width`, `length` and `scale` together.

Comment: @samcarter I did save the image in `pdf` format, but when I open it, above image divided to two pages. Why? How can I fix this? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you share a link to your draw.io project?

Comment: Can you try to change the paper size of your draw.io project? Assuming its Din A4 or similar now, change to Din A3?

Comment: @samcarter I still hasn't solved the problem yet. Looking forward your further assist. Thanks :)

Comment: unfortunately not. I get some `Authorization required` from goggle drive

Comment: @samcarter invitation is on the way :)

Comment: OK, quick and dirty: use Din A3 paper as size - this will give you an ugly boarder. Long answer, select custom paper size and match it to the dimension of your image, which is 1000pt x 1130pt (you will have to move your image to the of the paper, which is marked by the dashed lines) and then export to pdf while selecting the "crop" option

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for your effort. How can I learn your solution on my sites? Your answer is great, I want to learn it. Thanks again :)

Comment: I only did what I wrote in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359633/how-to-keep-the-original-resolution-of-inserted-image-in-sharelatex?noredirect=1#comment886204_359633

Comment: @samcarter I'll do upvote your answer when I have enough credit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such graphics containing text and sharp lines it is better to use a vector format such as `.pdf`. From `draw.io`, you can export it to `.pdf`

[image]

This pdf can be included in the same way you currently include your image, but to avoid image distortion, only specify either `width`, `length` or `scale`.

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{workflow}
    %\centering
    \caption{workflow}
    \label{fig: workflow}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Be sure to select "crop" in draw.io when exporting pdf; otherwise, a whole image with lots of blank space is exported in pdf as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that if you're using `a4paper` this has dimensions of 2480 px by 3508 px at 300 dpi. That's two times what your image has. But you force it to fit your page's width, what scales it. Since png and jpg are raster graphic formats you will see those blurs.

A possible solution would be to just use `\includegraphics{workflow}` (equals `\includegraphics[scale=1]{workflow}`) or to produce scalable graphics like svg or pdf.